# Python 3 Encoding Issues when converting to CSV from JSON

Tags: python, json, character-encoding, ascii, utf

Python3

I have looked at the other solutions but they havent seem to have covered the situation I am. I have been charged with writing a script to take JSON and convert it to a CSV file.

I have a good chunk of this done but have encountered an issue when I write the data. The data I received does not match what was written. Below is an example. I am lost on how I can get this to preserve the encoding.

I should mention that the default encoding is UTF-8

Input: necesitará

Output: necesitarÃ¡

```
import csv
import json
import sys
import sys
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
stuff = open('data.json')

jsonStuff = json.loads(stuff.read(), encoding="utf-8")
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",",quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for element in jsonStuff:
        row = ""
        key = element['key']
        values = element['valuesRow']

        row = element['key']
        # values[0]['value'], values[1]['value'], values[2]['value'], values[3]['value'],

        writer.writerow([element['key'], values[3]['value']])
```

Comment: Showing us your code would probably be a good start...

Comment: maybe you first use `.encode('utf-8')` and then do your conversions?

Comment: I'm not actually converting it. I want to preserve the format it was in.

Comment: I know flask uses ascii by default for its json responses. Maybe your writer does as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `encoding='utf-8'` in `open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8')` should fix it.

---

data.json (utf-8): `{"first": "necesitará", "second": "bodø"}`

The following ...

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.json') as stuff, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    jsonStuff = json.loads(stuff.read(), encoding="utf-8")
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    first = jsonStuff['first']
    second = jsonStuff['second']
    writer.writerow([first, second])
```

... gives output.csv: `necesitarÃ¡,bodÃ¸`

However ...

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.json') as stuff, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='\n') as csvfile:
    jsonStuff = json.loads(stuff.read(), encoding="utf-8")
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    first = jsonStuff['first']
    second = jsonStuff['second']
    writer.writerow([first, second])
```

... produces output.csv: `necesitará,bodø`

That said. There is no reason to use `json.loads()` when you have `json.load()`, and most of what you've defined are the defaults. I'd simply do ...

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.json') as jsonfile, open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    json_data = json.load(jsonfile)
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    first = json_data['first']
    second = json_data['second']
    writer.writerow([first, second])
```